# Does it make any difference if columns used only in UPDATE queries are indexed

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say there are two columns of type `int` in a SQL Server. Values in these two columns are frequently updated for a single row using the `ROWLOCK` hint and the unique row Id which is a PK.

For example

```
UPDATE SomeTable WITH(ROWLOCK) 
SET SuccessCount = {0}, ErrorCount = {1} 
WHERE RecordId = {2}
```

If `SuccessCount` and `ErrorCount` are not used in any `SELECT` queries, performance-wise does it make any difference if these two columns are added to a non-clustered index of `SomeTable`?

Comment: It can make a difference whether or not the columns in the `WHERE` criteria are properly indexed, since that row (or those rows) have to be found first, before they can be updated. But I don't think that having an index on the columns being *updated* makes any difference - the update will have to be written back to the data page anyway, so that page needs to be fetched from the cache (or disk)

Comment: It probably will make some (negative) difference because you will have to update not only the table itself, but also the values of `SuccessCount` and `ErrorCount` in the non-clustered index.

Comment: An index is meta data about a table.  So including an index on data that changes which is never directly searched by (read where index is never used) DOES add overhead as the engine has to maintain the index.  If these two fields are NEVER searched by directly, then the index with these columns in it is pointless overhead.  Indexes should be added only if the benefits from reduced search time (frequency and time savings) outweigh the cost of maintaining the index (overhead any insert,update or delete)

Comment: @xQbert That was my thinking but wanted to check with DB experts... If you post as answer I'll mark as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index is meta data about a table.

Including an index on data that changes which is never directly searched by (read where index is never used) DOES add overhead as the engine has to maintain the index. If these two fields are NEVER searched by directly, then the index with these columns in it is pointless overhead.

Indexes should be added only if the benefits from reduced search time (frequency and time savings) outweigh the cost of maintaining the index (overhead any insert,update or delete)

In this case there will never be a benefit as they are never directly searched upon.  Thus, pure cost; no savings... don't do it.